# DRUPAL 7 - How to ajax refresh a view IF new content has been added to it from elsewhere? Like Facebook

Tags: ajax, view, drupal-7, refresh, feed

I am currently working on a news feed view for the user where he/she can se what friends have uploaded. But what i can't get to work is so that **when somebody uploads new content it automatically appears on everybody's feed instantly without the need to reload the page**

It seems that Facebook does this automatically if the user clicks anywhere on the page.

Any help would be welcome, this would really kick up the value of the page!

And if it works, would this be able to work with for example comments and other content?

Answer (score 1):

This would require long polling or push notifications.  That's pretty easily handled with nodejs, to do this without something like nodejs would be nightmarish though, and dramatically increase server load as it would require browsers to continually ping the server.

Whereas, with nodejs, you could leverage socket.io or something similar, to establish the asynch tunnel between the browser and server, and then implement pub/sub.  Basically the way it would work would be like this:

Nodejs handles asych communication between browsers and server, on initial page load, current content is shuttled over to the browser by standard http request as normal.  Additionally a tunnel is opened to the nodejs server and the user is subscribed to a channel for that page.

Someone posts a new node, and within a node_save hook an event is fired off to the nodejs server with details about the newly published node.  The new data is then fired off to the channel, and all browsers connected to the page, and therefore subscribed to the channel, receive the new data which causes some client side javascript to update the view with the new data -- OR -- refresh the view.

It's complex, and not something you'll be able to just plug in and make work out of the box.  The nodejs integration module (http://drupal.org/project/nodejs) ships with an example of this for the drupal log.. What you're looking to do could probably be implemented in a manner similar to that example.